# How to catch event of status changed in Invoice Screen

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I am doing customization in Invoice Screen (SO303000).

I want to catch event when status of invoice is changed from Balanced to Open.  Can you suggest event which I will use for this?

Answer (score 3):

This screen has as graph class: PX.Objects.SO.SOInvoiceEntry. You need to make extension like this:

```
public class SOInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{
    protected virtual void ARInvoice_Status_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here goes reaction on changing field status. 
    //you can get ARInvoice in the following way:
   ARInvoice invoice = (ARInvoice) e.Row;
}

}
```

Comment: It does not work, I try to debug this event but nothing happened.

Comment: Make customization, and in form SO303000.aspx add CommitChanges="True" to field status